# Why is this jasmine spy and callFake not working?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm am trying to spyOn a component function and replace it with this callFake function but jasmine is not calling that function (and it is obvious that the original function is still being called due to errors). Does anyone know why?

```
    it('should call handleFileList x times', () => {
      console.log('run test');
      spyOn(component, 'handleFileList').and.callFake(()=>{console.log('callFake');});
      component.filesDropped(filesDropped);
      // tick();
      expect(component.handleFileList).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    });
```

Comment: Please give a [mre]. In general, though, *don't* spy on the thing you claim to be testing.

Comment: we generally mock the service and utilities methods. so this SpyOn.and.callFake works in case of services and utilities so if you want to mock a component function then you have to create the component in spec file ( mock replica of component function you want to mock) and then declare that function in the declaration of the component TestBad

Comment: @SunnyGoel Ah fair enough. I suppose this is a case of trying to make a bad test. Maybe i'll just delete it